# Another one on when an answer is not an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I have resisted a couple of days trying to understand why the "not-an-answer" flag I raised on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35902052/1) has been declined.

So far I understand that if you remove the question mark and move the verb after the subject you could, with a lot of logical stress, argue that this is an answer.

But I really feel discouraged by a declined flag accompanied by "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". I think that this could be a disputed flag instead.

Well, at least, if this is explained, that answer could be used as an example on how to handle the NAA flags.

Comment: Just to note - mods can only dispute spam or offensive flags. All the others are either helpful or declined only.

Comment: @JonClements this was not know to me. Thanks.

Comment: [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135920/288751). Basically, edit if you can, comment if the user is active and you can't edit, use a custom flag explaining that you've done your due diligence if you can't edit and the user is not active, or has responded and doesn't want to improve their answer. When using a custom flag, make sure to be very descriptive about the situation, and why the answer is actively causing harm to the site.

Comment: This is exactly why I tend to avoid flagging anything as NAA. The mental gymnasts here are well-equipped to argue that if an answer contains at least one string of characters that *could* be confused with an English word among garbage is, unequivocally, an answer. The flag is useless; everything is an answer.

Comment: @That1Guy You can still downvote as useless. Although just requiring that an answer shall be formulated as a statement doesn't really change anything, does it?

Comment: @Trilarion Not in my opinion, if you write a short one line sentence ending with a question mark, you are asking for something. If you ask for something (clarifications) then you are not responding to the question. If you write a short and affirmative one line sentence then you are saying: _This is your problem and this is the way I think you could solve it_ This is what triggered my flagging

Comment: @Steve I think this approach is rather formal. Usually, people do not make much of a difference between "You should check line 10." and "Have you checked line 10?" But if you insist that it should rather only be a statement I would agree. But I would prefer if this were a general policy and explicitly written down somewhere on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion I suppose I should have said, "This is an example of why...". The terribly broad definition of "answer" on this site precludes the removal of the drivel the community so vehemently despises. Treating  posts such as these as "answers" while maintaining a NAA flag is the Q&A version of "stop hitting yourself".

Comment: @Steve I disagree. There is such a thing as a rhetorical question, which contains or implies its own answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know who declined your flag or why, but here's my best guess:

At the end of the day, it's hard to argue that an accepted answer qualifies for NAA, since by definition an accepted answer (abuse notwithstanding) is one that solved the OP's problem.

In this case, I can totally see where you're coming from, but this *one* question was enough to help the OP realize their mistake. In a case like this, I think it would be best to edit the answer; a much better alternative to the answerer logging in one day and finding their answer gone/downvoted. I've gone ahead and edited it into the form of a statement.

Comment: A [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35934947/2193767) was flagged as NAA but it was not (not judging whether it is right or wrong, only saying that **it does try to answer the question**).  NAA -> Doesn't try to answer the question and is not SPAM.

Comment: I should have to think about the same thing. Your action is probably the best thing to do here.

Comment: Does it really matter if an answer is formulated as a question? I mean, it doesn't really matter if a sentence is a question or a statement, does it? Every statement is kind of a question in disgiuse because one never really knows, does one? However, for the sake of brevity, I propose that we should suggest that all answers are written as statements instead as questions. This is probably a good idea. Apart from that I would say that your edit did not change anything substantial about the answer. It's still the same as it was before. The NAA decline was okay.

Comment: @Trilarion That comment probably belongs as a [tag:feature-request]. But for the record I agree; it's not really an absolute necessity for an answer to be formulated 100% as a declarative statement. I've recently commented similarly on a question being asked that didn't include an interrogative statement where another user was arguing that was reason enough for the Q to be closed.

Comment: `since by definition an accepted answer is one that solved the OP's problem.`  That's not actually true.  An accepted answer is one that the OP has claimed solved their problem.  They can accept spam as an answer even if it didn't solve their problem, if they feel like it.  Because of this it's pretty rare for an accepted answer to be NAA, but it can happen.  That's why they go to mods, rather than /review.

Comment: @TylerH I absolutely agree it should be a feature-request or a discussion on policy/best practise, but I don't want to bring it forward right now, actually I like it the way it is. One can see very clearly from the way you edited it "It seem like... should be ..." that your statement is as strong/weak as any question would be. And the question was even more concise in this case. But taking human psychology into account it's probably better as it is now.

Comment: @Servy Okay, you're right: I'm operating on the assumption that OP is not lying about an answer solving their problem, which I think the tooltip assumes as well. It's true OP could also be an evil robot kitten rather than a human but pedantic possibilities aren't really productive to the discussion at hand.

Comment: @TylerH It's *extremely* relevant to the discussion at hand.  Sometimes an OP will accept an answer that isn't even an answer.  Maybe it'll be a misclick, maybe they don't even know what the button does, maybe they just don't care, etc.  The whole point is that it's uncommon, but sometimes non-answers are accepted, and should still be deleted.

Comment: @Servy Those would be instances of misusing the accepted answer feature outside of its defined use. If this is acceptance abuse, in my opinion that is a very similar, but distinct, problem from whether this answer is NAA. Since the question is about flagging as NAA, my answer tackles the scenario from that perspective, without assuming misuse of a very basic, clear cut feature..

Comment: @TylerH The OP is allowed to accept whatever answer they want.  The only possibility for abuse, under the rules, would be some form of rep fraud in which a user accepted the answer of another one of his accounts, or something along those lines.  If the OP accepts an answer that's Not An Answer they aren't breaking any rules, but the answer that is not an answer still merits flagging accordingly, and should be deleted.  Oh, and I don't even see how you think a misclick, or someone not using a feature that don't understand the purpose of, as abuse.  It's not.

Comment: @Servy From the Tour: "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked." From the Help Center: "Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem." and "It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally". That is pretty clear cut. If you are accepting an answer that doesn't solve your problem, that's your right within the system, but it's clear misuse of the feature. Oh, and abuse doesn't have to be malicious or intentional. It's nearly a direct synonym of "misuse".

Comment: @TylerH Those are all guidelines for how we want people to use the system.  They are not requirements that a moderator can, or will, enforce.  If you flag a post because the OP accepted an answer that you think didn't solve their problem they're only ever going to decline your flag.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say they would accept it or enforce it or that they should, only that it's not the same issue as an answer being NAA.

Comment: @TylerH Where did I say it was?  All I've said is that if an answer is not an answer it should be deleted, and that the OP accepting a non-answer doesn't automatically make it an answer.

Comment: @Servy I think we are going in circles.